# Решение задачи оптимизации в рамках ООП

Tags: c++, ооп, оптимизация, градиент

Не могу правильно подобрать структуру классов и методов для решения задачи оптимизации именно в стиле ООП. 
**Дано:** функция с ограничениями (равенства и неравенства) для примера возьмем простую нелинейную функцию с ограничением равенством

```
x^2 + y^2 -> min
x + y = 1
```

**Метод решения:** метод штрафных функций для преобразования функции и ограничения в единую функцию, оптимизация может производиться любым методом безусловной оптимизации, я например разбираю градиентный спуск.

**Как я решал:**

1. Оптимизировал простые целевые функции без ограничений градиентным методом, имел два класса - Задачу (Problem) с функциями выдающими значение функции и ее градиента и класс градиентный спуск (GradientDescent) со всеми свойственными ему методами. В `main` создавал объекты двух классов и массив `double *point` с начальными значениями точки, объект `problem` и `gradient_descent`. После чего, `problem` и `point` передавал в инициализатор `gradient_descent` и запускал метод `optimize`.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Оптимизировал функции с ограничениями методом штрафных функций, соответственно методы `getF` и `getG` изменились добавился "коэффициент резкого возрастания функции" `gamma`, а оптимизация попала в цикл с изменяющимся параметром `gamma`.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. На основе вышеописанного хотелось бы писать код в рамках ООП. На сколько я понял лучше и удобнее - пользоваться наследованием. А именно - создать абстрактный класс `Problem` со всеми свойственными ему атрибутами и методами и парой переопределяемых методов, например `virtual bool solve()` и от него унаследовать класс например `GradientDescent:Problem` дабы просто использовать методы и атрибуты класса родителя и не передавать какието объекты и параметры.
   Однако я не могу никак придумать "связку" наследования `Задача -> Метод штрафных функций -> Любой метод безусловной оптимизации`.
   Может ли кто нибудь "на пальцах" объяснить возможна ли такая связка?
   Пока что в голову приходит только что в методе класса `PenaltyM` будет крутиться цикл с `GradientDescent:Problem`.

**UPD**
По хорошему это ведь может касаться не только моей конкретной задачи. А задач на подобии:

```
        |----------------> Method_1
        |------>Method_0-----^
Problem |----------------> Method_2
        |----------------> Method_3
        |------>Method_4-----^
```

Т.е. по идее должен быть какой-то обобщенный класс метод, который может наследоваться от проблемы напрямую или иметь промежуточный метод. К сожалению я мыслю в формате процедурном, может быть кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным и сможет направить?
Методы 1,2 и 3 должны как-то узнать, что их функцию оптимизации запускают либо просто так либо еще и через методы 0 или 4.

**UPD 2**
Я нашел один из подходов который решает мою задачу, но он не универсален. Как сделать так чтобы PenaltyMethod стал универсальным - я пока что не могу адекватно представить и реализовать. Ну а по делу, код выглядит так:

```
class Problem{
public:
    Problem(){}
    Problem (int size,
             double *point,
             double *constr_non_eq,
             bool **constr_eq):size_(size),
                              point_(point),
                              constrains_non_eq_(constr_non_eq),
                              constrains_eq_(constr_eq){}
    virtual ~Problem(){}
    virtual double *getResult() = 0;
    virtual bool solve() = 0;
protected:
    virtual double getFunctionVal(){}
    long size_;
    double *point_;
    double *constrains_non_eq_;
    bool **constrains_eq_;
};

class GradDesc : Problem{
public:
    GradDesc():Problem(){}
    GradDesc(int size,
             double *point,
             double *constr_non_eq,
             bool **constr_eq,
             double min_step_lenght,
             double min_eps,
             double min_iter): min_step_lenght_(min_step_lenght),
                               min_eps_(min_eps),
                               min_iter_(min_iter),
                               Problem(size, point, constr_non_eq, constr_eq){}
    virtual bool getGradientVal(){}
    bool solve() override {
        optimize();
    }
    double *getResult() override{}
    bool optimize() {
        // optimization, will use private methods
        // getNewPoint and getGradientNorm
    }
protected:
    bool getNewPoint(){}
    double getGradientNorm(){}


    double *grad_;
    double min_step_lenght_;
    double min_eps_;
    int min_iter_;
};

class PenaltyMethod : GradDesc{
public:
    PenaltyMethod():GradDesc(){}
    PenaltyMethod(int size,
                  double *point,
                  double *constr_non_eq,
                  bool **constr_eq,
                  double min_step_lenght,
                  double min_eps,
                  double min_iter,
                  int gamma_start,
                  double mult,
                  double accuracy):gamma_(gamma_start),
                                   mult_(mult),
                                   accuracy_(accuracy),
                                   GradDesc(size, point, constr_non_eq, constr_eq,min_step_lenght,min_eps,min_iter){}
    bool solve() override {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; ++i) {
            optimize();
        }
    }
    double *getResult() override{}
protected:
    double getFunctionVal() override{}
    bool getGradientVal() override{}

private:
    int gamma_;
    double mult_;
    double accuracy_;

};


int main() {

    int size = 3;
    double *point = new double[size];
    double *constr_non_eq = new double[15];
    bool ** constr_eq = new bool*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; ++i) {
        constr_eq[i] = new bool[9];
    }

    PenaltyMethod *pm = new PenaltyMethod(size,point,constr_non_eq, constr_eq,1e-5,1e-5,50,1,10,1e-10);
    pm->solve();
    pm->getResult();

    return 0;
}
```

Напрягает нагромождение инициализации конструкторов и то что если у меня вдруг поменяется промежуточный метод оптимизации. То придется еще и от него наследовать метод Штрафных функций. В голове крутятся мысли по обобщению методов, но учитывая отсутствие опыта в С++ и незнакомство с шаблонами пока что приходится пользоваться такими вот костылями.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал посмотреть книгу *"Современный С++ для программистов, инженеров и ученых"* П. Готтшлинга - там есть пару примеров построения обобщенных решений задач - правда, там в основном используются шаблоны, но там стоит посмотреть сам принцип декомпозиции задачи, разделения решения на взаимодействующие части.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за направление, посмотрю что к чему в книге, но в принципе само по себе разделение задачи на подзадачи мне здесь кажется вполне понятным. Вопрос скорее касается способа реализации уже имеющегося разделения и как с помощью наследования пользоваться разными вариациями методов. P - PM - GD или P - PM - JGD или просто P - GD. Ведь задачи есть с условной и безусловной оптимизацией а для преобразования одной в другую нужно изменить вид целевой функции =/
Может есть какой - нибудь паттерн который подходит под это?

Comment: Как бы сказать... В программировании, как мне кажется, никогда нет единственно верного решения :), в том числе и в проектировании. Соответственно, я даже пытаться не буду давать конкретные советы, разве что - начните как-нибудь, потом, когда начнете использовать - придется переписать; как - покажет практика. Как по мне, как минимум не использовать массивы, а вместо них - контейнеры, и не функции, а обобщенные функциональные объекты. Наследование, конечно, вещь неплохая, но не "потому что так принято в ООП".

Comment: @Harry На счет вариантов решения - полностью согласен, их многое множество, тем более что в процедурном стиле я описал решение. Могу я поинтересоваться, чем вам не угодили массивы? ну по крайней мере в данном случае? =) Все таки хранить тот же вектор мне представляется нецелесообразным, ведь мне не нужно дополнять его или удалять элементы или пользоваться какими-то специфическими функциями, несколько избыточно на мой взгляд.

Comment: Исключительно исходя из обобщенности...

Comment: Вы должны применять ООП, чтобы сделать ваш код удобнее в разработке, а не чтобы в нём было больше ООП. ООП — лишь рабочее средство для вас. Если оно вам не помогает в данной проблеме, не пользуйтесь им для её решения.

Comment: @VladD ну ООП ради ООП само по себе бессмысленно, однако способов решения задачи много. В приведенном коде я представляю удобное решение задачи без передачи лишних объектов туда-сюда. Но мне не хватает унифицированности, хотя прекрасно понимаю что если поменяю метод градиента на что-нибудь другое, придется переделывать метод штрафных функций а ведь ему нужно лишь запускать оптимизацию с разным параметром гамма и целевой функцией содержащей ограничения.